# Spring microservice end-to-end testing

Tags: java, spring, testing

I'd like to write a end to end test for a pipeline, built with spring boot.

Consider two microservices A, B where B consumes output from A and produces a RESTful API. They are connected using rabbitmq and rely on an external database.

[image: System scheme]

I would like to achieve something like:

1. Create a new project that includes both microservices
2. Create a test configuration that configures JPA provider to be an in-memory database
3. Inject custom MQ into A, B to connect them (rabbitmq is not tightly coupled)
4. Write tests

Essentially replacing the white parts with mocks and testing the coloured parts.

Does this make sense? Test coverage of A and B is not complete and such a test would guarantee that the contract between A and B holds. Are there better ways?

Answer (score 3):

If you have the time, I suggest you to read this :
https://martinfowler.com/articles/microservice-testing/

The purpose of end-to-end testing is not to do 100% of line coverage.

Answer (score 3):

My first idea about this topic is that if it is an end-to-end test, then you should forget which framework do you use, because that relates to implementation in this context. So I would create a test project, which is essentially a docker-compose file, and defines 5 containers for

- service A
- service B
- RabbitMQ
- maybe database too, unless you want to stick to the in-memory approach
- and a separate container for running the tests

From this perspective you have 2 ways of handling env-specific configuration:

- you define test-specific config in a separate spring profile, and you activate it by defining the [`SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-set-active-spring-profiles) env var in the docker-compose file
- you  pass your config in a properties file, and mount it in the docker-compose file

The test runner can be kept simple, I would write a JUnit-based test suite which uses RestAssured, or something similar.

I hope this gives a clue. Of course it is a broad topic so going into every detail doesn't fit into a SO answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to use [Spring-cloud-contract](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/). It helps you in maintaining contract between your microservices(Producer-Consumer Contracts).
It's available for both HTTP based and event-based communication.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to test each component in isolation and mock the dependent service on the other side of the RabbitMQ server. You can do this using an [async API simulation/mocking tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_API_simulation_tools).

For example you can use [Traffic Parrot](https://trafficparrot.com) which can be run in a Docker container as part of your CI/CD pipeline.

Here is a [video demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YFYJHa3j3uc) of how you can use the tool to send mock response messages to a RabbitMQ queue in an [aysnc request/response pattern](https://dzone.com/articles/rabbitmq-request-response). There is also a corresponding [tutorial available](https://trafficparrot.com/tutorials/service-virtualization-mocking-or-simulating-rabbitmq.html) to follow.

[image: Request/Response RabbitMQ pattern]
[image: Recording gRPC messages]
[image: Replaying gRPC messages]